# Can the same generic function receive a pointer to both a member-function and a regular-function as a single argument?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, c++20, pointer-to-member

I currently have 2 nearly-identical (functionality-wise) functions:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void CallFunc(auto fncPtr)
    {
        fncPtr();
    }
    void CallMemFunc(auto (MyClass::*fncPtr)())
    {
        (this->*fncPtr)();
    }
};
```

Is there any way to combine both generic functions into a single generic function?

Either by somehow generalizing the function's parameter further, or by adding both as separate parameters (with some default values) to the function?

- To clarify, the above functions serve as a simple example to what I'm trying to achieve - My code has 2 functions with near-identical functionality that differ only by the fact that one of them handles a pointer-to-member-function while the other handles a pointer-to-general-function, like in the above case (though my issue isn't with the above functions per-se).

Comment: Please turn the code into a [mcve]. Currently you are using `this` outside of a class. If it is not a member function you would need to pass the instance anyhow (ie it has different signature)

Comment: it is also not clear what is your aim. You can rename `CallMemFunc` to `CallFun` to have two overloads with same name: https://godbolt.org/z/1saa9q7qx. It won't get much simpler than that

Comment: I've edited my question to include the class itself (so now both functions are member functions).
My aim is to have a single function definition in-code, as to avoid code duplication for clarity & maintainability purposes.

Comment: You can pass all and nearly everything through a template parameter. But did it make any sense? Later on you have to know what type you have to use it, in the given case you have to decide to use it as a callable or as a member pointer. So what can be simplified? Nothing in my eyes. You can get it in one function by using constexpr if... but why?

Comment: My solution would be to just use a lambda.

Comment: what duplicate code ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is what you want and if it is better than simple overload, but you can do:

```
void Call(auto func)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(func)>) {
        std::invoke(func);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(func), MyClass*>) {
        std::invoke(func, this);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hcdGKe4YM)